# Add all elements of a list of MouseAdapter to a JComponent

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, event-listener, jcomponent

I have an array of `JLabel`s, and I have a list of lists holding `MouseAdapter`s. The idea is that there is one list of `MouseAdapter`s for each `JLabel`. I want to iterate over these lists and add the `MouseAdapter`s to each `JLabel`.

```
JLabel[] labels;
ArrayList<ArrayList<MouseAdapter>> labelBehaviors;
```

However, you can't add `MouseAdapter`s to a `JComponent`: they have to be cast to `MouseListener`, `MouseMotionListener`, etc. and then added with their corresponding methods. Is there a way that I can do this, other than determining if the `MouseAdapter` is an instance of `MouseListener`, `MouseMotionListener`, etc., then casting it and adding it with the proper method?

I'm trying to do this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < LABEL_COUNT; i++ ) {
  JLabel label = labels[i];
  if ( label != null ) {
    // Add associated behaviors to the label.
    for ( MouseAdapter behavior : labelBehaviors.get( i ) ) {
      // addMouseEventListener() doesn't exist...
      label.addMouseEventListener( behavior );
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want to do something like this, unless there isn't an easier way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LABEL_COUNT; i++ ) {
  JLabel label = labels[i];
  if ( label != null ) {
    // Add associated behaviors to the label.
    for ( MouseAdapter behavior : labelBehaviors.get( i ) ) {
      // Check type of behavior.
      if ( behavior instanceof MouseListener ) {
        label.addMouseListener( (MouseListener) behavior );
      } else if ( behavior instanceof MouseMotionListener ) {
        label.addMouseMotionListener( (MouseMotionListener) behavior );
      } else if ( behavior instanceof MouseWheelListener ) {
        label.addMouseWheelListener( (MouseWheelListener) behavior );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a simpler way, perhaps involving the type signature of `labelBehaviors`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MouseAdapter` implements all three interfaces. If the methods aren't overridden, they will do nothing. In short, you can skip these checks since all of them will return true because of the declaration

```
public abstract class MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener
```

The simplified loop is

```
for ( MouseAdapter behavior : labelBehaviors.get( i ) ) {
    label.addMouseListener( behavior );
    label.addMouseMotionListener( behavior );
    label.addMouseWheelListener( behavior );
}
```

Comment: Of course! Can't believe I didn't realize that. That very characteristic is the reason I was using `MouseAdapter` in the first place. Thanks!